# Access VBA - can't access Series.Name in a chart

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to use VBA to colour the series in a chart by matching the names of the series to a table containing the colour values for each series (tblTypes). My only problem is retrieving the names of the series, which I've consistently read is accessed by SeriesCollection(index).Name. The weird thing is, SeriesCollection() doesn't seem to be returning a Series object. Here's the relevant code:

```
Private Sub ReformatColoursByType(grphChart As Object)
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim iii As Integer
    Dim objSeries As Series

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTypes", RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)
    rs.MoveFirst

    Do
        For iii = 1 To grphChart.SeriesCollection.Count
            Set objSeries = grphChart.SeriesCollection(iii) -- !!! This line is the problem !!! --
            If objSeries.Name = rs!rwType Then
                ... formatting ...
            End If
        Next iii
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop Until rs.EOF
End Sub
```

The line highlighted above returns a "type mismatch" error - grphChart.SeriesCollection(iii) is not of type "Series" for some reason. What's gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that are wrong.

In your code `grphChart` is a [ChartObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartobject) - a container for the chart, not the chart itself.

Instead use:

```
grphChart.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
```

and

```
grphChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(iii)
```

The second problem is `Dim objSeries As Series`.  You've tagged the question as `Access` and, *I think*, your code is referencing Excel.
If it's late binding then Access won't understand what a `Series` is - you need to define it as an `Object`.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll give it a try. Also, <code>Dim objSeries As Series</code> seems to be possible - the Series type comes up in IntelliSense and the Object Browser, and the macro compiles fine - but I do have to include an Excel library to provide the definition for the type... maybe this is the source of the issue?

Comment: Yes, that's ok - if you've got the reference to the library (early binding) then Access will give you IntelliSense and understand Excel.  I think the solution is just to add the `Chart` to the `ChartObject` then.

Comment: Hm. Tried it to no avail - now it returns "method or property not defined" when trying to do grphChart.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count, which worked fine before... I think I may be coming to the conclusion that there just isn't a way to do it with the Access API - Series just won't reveal their names and that's just it.